# How can I get Webpack to parse JSX in my index.js?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jsx, babel-loader

I am trying to add React to my project built by Webpack.

No matter what I try, however, Webpack cannot read `<>` (JSX) in my file. Here is the error it throws every time I build it.

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 16:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (16:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| ReactDOM.render(
>     <h1>Hello World</h1>,
|   document.getElementById('root')
| );
```

Here are my import statements:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
```

Here are the relevant bits of my package.json for Webpack:

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack": "^5.78.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.30.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(?:js|mjs|cjs)$/,
        "exclude": [
          /node_modules[\\/]core-js/,
          /node_modules[\\/]webpack[\\/]buildin/,
        ],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: "defaults" }, '@babel/preset-react']
            ],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  module: {
    parser: {
      javascript: {
        // ...
        commonjsMagicComments: true,
      },
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

And finally, here is my babel.config.json:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "edge": "17",
          "firefox": "60",
          "chrome": "67",
          "safari": "11.1"
        },
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": "3.6.5"
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "pragma": "dom", // default pragma is React.createElement (only in classic runtime)
        "pragmaFrag": "DomFrag", // default is React.Fragment (only in classic runtime)
        "throwIfNamespace": false, // defaults to true
        "runtime": "classic" // defaults to classic
        // "importSource": "custom-jsx-library" // defaults to react (only in automatic runtime)
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Notes:

- When I remove the offending `<>` from my index.js file, the project builds with no errors.
- I have consulted all of these resources:

  - https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#the-nodejs-api-for-babel-has-been-moved-to-babel-core
  - https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-preset-react
  - https://babeljs.io/setup#installation
  - https://react.dev/learn/add-react-to-an-existing-project
- I have fiddled around with core js and various cleaning up

Comment: Start by changing the file extension from `.js` to `.jsx`

Answer (score 0):

I acknowledged your problem i guess. According to me , if you are trying to build your react project manually using webpack and babel, then you should install "HtmlWebpackPlugin". I hereby attach a sample webpack.config.js code for your reference:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin =
require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],

            },
        ],
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
            filename: './index.html',
        }),
    ],
};
```

Here, i have imported "HtmlWebpackPlugin" in the webpack.config.js file. Moreover, if you see, you should consider changing the code line:

```
test: /\.(?:js|mjs|cjs)$/
```

as:

```
test: /\.jsx?$/
```

Now, for detecting HTML file, you should consider putting the code:

```
{
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "html-loader"
                }
            ]
        }
```

So the final code block that you can consider inserting in the webpack.config.js is given as:

```
{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "html-loader"
                }
            ]
        }
```

So, according to me, trying to configure this webpack.config.js in the specified way, can help you to resolve your error.